# Why does the center / origin jump back?

Tags: origin

[image]

I have imported an fbx into Unity, and the center is at the bottom of the grenade.

[image]

But this is not what I want. The origin / center should be in the middle.

To set the origin / center correctly, I import the fbx into Blender.

In Blender, I set the geometry to the 3D cursor, and the origin as at the same location.

This is what it looks like this:

[image]

It looks perfectly fine and as I need it.

Then I export it as an fbx, and right after saving, it looks like this in Blender:

[image]

Why does the center jump back to the bottom?

And then in Unity, I have the same problem again.

What might be the problem here?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you apply location with ctrl+a?

Comment: I did that now, and the problem stays the same: Right after exporting as an fbx, it jumps back.

Comment: That's strange. Just to confirm, after you apply location, if you press N and look in the toolbox, does the location read 0,0,0?

Comment: Also, I notice your mesh is in 3 parts, join them first with ctrl+j

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you. I did join them now, but it still keeps jumping back after exporting.

Comment: Hmm. that's really strange. I'm afraid i'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you anyways!

Comment: No problem I'm playing with it, it's got me interested. For me, whenever I export, it scales itself down really really tiny, and I cant scale it up in any way that will stick.

Comment: I have filed a bug report here: https://developer.blender.org/T78052

Comment: No. don't bother, I found the problem. I'm posting as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it - the problem is a keyframe sitting in your timeline. If you delete it, the objects transforms become "unlocked" and your changes will stay. See images below:

[image: Keyframe]

[image: Deleted]

Comment: Wow, thank you!!