# Blender 4 Move gizmo is frozen object teleports back

Tags: animation, rigging

The issue Iam experiencing is related to the object's transformation gizmo not updating correctly while the object is moving. When I try to change the position of an object, it jumps back to the gizmo's coordinates that were set there before. It's as if there's an option disabled somewhere, like update_gizmo_on_frame_update.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190761/what-do-various-property-highlight-color-overlays-mean/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183346/why-does-the-center-origin-jump-back https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141410/object-moves-back-into-origin-everytime-i-open-the-blender-file

Comment: Can you please provide a .blend file for some context?